# Feature state is not getting evaluated during MSI Installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Tool used : WIX.

Technology :Windows Installer

I have an MSI with 10 features, all 10 features are shown in the UI, User can select/deselect the desired features.
By default all 10 features are marked as selected (in my features.wxs file).
I have a custom action that copies/deployed few files and performs necessary actions based on what features are selected.
for example: if feature A is selected the respective folder for A is copied to user PC and certain actions are performed.

All of the above works fine if I schedule my custom action as DoAction on the click of next button in feature selection dialog, but if I schedule if elsewhere in UI or execute sequence, the feature evaluation is not happening (always all 10 features are selected i.e. default values are retained).

I have tried the below workarounds and none of it works:

1. I have scheduled the custom Action right after CostFinalize.
2. I have tried to CostFinalize inside my custom action using MSIdoactionA().

Kindly suggest what changes needs to be adapted.

Comment: Could you elaborate what these custom actions do? Do they actually copy files themselves or is that done by regular MSI installation mechanisms? Not totally relevant for what you asked, but [here is an old anser on features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50556535/129130).

Comment: They copy files and import some registries.. i cannot use the normal msi mechanisms to do these actions due to some condition constraints.

Comment: Read This blog article: http://blog.iswix.com/2011/10/beam-me-up-using-json-to-serialize.html

Comment: You should not use custom actions to copy files in place like this. You can do that during application launch after installing the files as read-only copies to proper locations on disk. What settings are you customizing and what operations are you doing?